# CSS div doesn't fill top and left

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to make a fixed header by putting my header content inside a div with a fixed position. Below is the CSS code for the div:

```
#page_header {
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and this is the effect of my div, (screenshot of the left top corner):
[image: left top corner of the div]

You can clearly see that there is a space between the div(white part) and the page, while it is not the case on the right side, how should I get rid of this space?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `body{margin:0;padding:0}`

Comment: Yep, thanks, body{margin:0;padding:0} works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your margins and padding are zeroed:

```
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

Moreover, if you really want the thing fixed in place, the best thing is to lock it there.

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the actual page to margin:0 and padding: 0 to the actual html, not just the body.

use this in your css stylesheet.

```
*, html {
margin:0;
padding:0;  
}
```

that will set the whole page to 0, for a fresh clean start with no margin or paddings.

Comment: By adding * you'll be removing all the spacing from all the tags like UL,OL,H1 etc. It'll add extra overhead of specifying space for each and every element.